# Prove that for any convex function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$: this is true

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xckz7.png)

> There exist sequences $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{\beta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, such that $$f(x) = \sup_{n\ge1} (\alpha_n x + \beta_n ); \quad x \in \mathbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the epigraph of $f$ and use the separation theorem which states that every closed ball can be separated from the horseteeth.

Comment: Could you comment on what is the horseteeth? I tried to google, but it failed

Comment: "horseteeth" ... I'm familiar with the separation theorem, but not with the diction

Comment: Also, can you elaborate a bit. It certainly seems clear that one could represent $f$ as the supremum of all supporting hyperplanes, but there are uncountably many of those. How can we show that there exists a countable set of hyperplanes whose supremum yields $f(x)$ at all points in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @David The function is convex and therefore continuous. So it suffices to consider the "tangent" lines at rational points.

Comment: @Farnight ah that makes sense, thanks! Now, if the range of $f$ was the extended reals, we couldn't use that same argument though correct? In that case we might need uncountably many hyperplanes?

Comment: @David Why doesn't the same argument work for a function into the extended reals?

Comment: @farnight I don't believe that convexity on an open set implies continuity of non-finite functions or functions in infinite-dimensional spaces. If it does, I'd be interested in seeing a proof.

Comment: @David I doubt that convex functions are always continuous in infinite dimensional spaces, but the question specified $\mathbb{R}$, so I'm just working with that. I still don't see how non-finite values change much. I think the only such functions are trivial. (finite on some interval, infinite everywhere else)

Comment: The problem with the theorem when you extend it to the extended reals is that you don't have supporting hyperplanes for those points where $f$ is infinite.  If you just use the supporting hyperplanes at rational values of $x$ where $f(x)$ is finite, then you might find that the sup at one of those points where $f$ is infinite is something less than infinity.

Comment: For example, try $f(x)=x^2\;\; x \geq 0, +\infty \;\; x< 0$.  What's the sup at $x=-1$?